# Why does my NVMe shows up twice?

Tags: debian, nvme, proxmox

Running Debian (ProxMox), why do all my NVMe shows up twice?

It is quite confusing which one I should use when trying to perform CLI operations.

```
# ls /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX*

/dev/disk/by-id/nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX  
/dev/disk/by-id/nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX_1
```

### Update 1

```
# ls -l nvme-T*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Feb 12 15:42 nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../nvme2n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Feb 12 15:42 nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX_1 -> ../../nvme2n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 15:42 nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX_1-part1 -> ../../nvme2n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 15:42 nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX_1-part2 -> ../../nvme2n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 15:42 nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX_1-part3 -> ../../nvme2n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 15:42 nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX-part1 -> ../../nvme2n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 15:42 nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX-part2 -> ../../nvme2n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 15:42 nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_XXXXXXXXXXXX-part3 -> ../../nvme2n1p3
```

Comment: What paths do each of those resolve to? Do both duplicate links point to the same device or not?

Comment: how do I figure that out? I call them duplicates because the XXXX is the serial # and they are both the same

Comment: They're regular symlinks, so `ls -l` or `readlink` would show their targets.

Comment: yes, they are pointing to the same target, see my OP update